# MySQL | REGEXP VS Like

Tags: mysql, regex, database-performance

I have a table CANDIDATE in my db which is running under MySQL 5.5 and I am trying to get rows from table where RAM is contains in firstname, so I can run below two queries, but I would like to know which query we should use for long term with respect to optimization.

```
SELECT * FROM CANDIDATE c WHERE firstname REGEXP 'ram';
SELECT * FROM CANDIDATE c WHERE firstname LIKE'%ram%';
```

Comment: Just to note, if you are looking for instances of a character / character set, use a regex.

Comment: @JustinE - Before version 8.0, utf8 multi-byte characters were not handled correctly by REGEXP.

Answer (score 19):

## LIKE vs REGEXP in MySQL

- Single condition: LIKE is faster
- Multiple conditions: REGEXP is faster

### Example

A real-world example could be: finding all rows containing escaped carriage returns of CRLF, LF, or CR.

#### Single condition

```sql
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE text LIKE '%\\\\n%';  Faster
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE text REGEXP '\\\\n';  Slower
```

#### Multiple conditions

```sql
SELECT * FROM comments
WHERE text LIKE '%\\\\r\\\n%'
OR text LIKE '%\\\\n%'
OR text LIKE '%\\\\r%';  Slower

SELECT * FROM comments
WHERE text REGEXP '((\\\\r\\\\n)|(\\\\(n|r)))';  Faster
```

### Conclusion

Use `LIKE` for single condition queries, and `REGEXP` for multiple condition queries.

Answer (score 16):

I've tried it out on `MySQL 8.0.13` and compared `LIKE` vs `REGEXP` on a table with 1M+ rows on a column with an index:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%foobar%';
```

Query took 10.0418 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, 'foobar');
```

Query took 11.0742 seconds.

`LIKE` performance is faster. If you can get away with using it instead of `REGEXP`, do it.

Answer (score 12):

`REGEXP` and `LIKE` are used to totally different cases.

`LIKE` is used to add wildcards to a string whereas `REGEXP` is used to match an attribute with Regular Expressions.

In your case a `firstname` is more likely to be matched using `LIKE` than `REGEXP` and hence, it will be more optimized.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use LIKE instead of REGEXP, use LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Better Use of LIKE Query instead of REGEXP if you are not sure about value.

Also LIKE is much faster than REGEXP.

Comment: Could you provide any information supporting the statement "LIKE is much faster than REGEXP"