# MySQL regex matching rows containing two or more spaces in a row

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to write a MySQL statement which finds and returns the book registrations that contain 2 or more spaces in a row.

The statement below is wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles REGEXP '[:space]{2,}';
```

Comment: Can you explain why this statement does not work for you?

Comment: Try with `SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles LIKE '%<two_spaces>%'`. Since the 2 spaces already meet your condition, you really do not need to check if there are more than 2. I have just tried that and it seems to work. If you need to match a regular ASCII space (dec. code 32), you do not need a REGEXP.

Comment: because I'm getting also results which have just 1 space

Comment: @sotirios: Don't you think `LIKE` is more efficient? Unless you need to match any whitespace, I'd choose a LIKE-based solution.

Comment: I haven't understood exactly the difference between like and regexp yet. I am beginner. I think your like statement can return results with exactly 2 spaces. Not more.

Comment: but thank you for your time too!

Comment: @sotirios: I posted my answer as I see you got interested. If you want to express gratitude, you can now upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 2 spaces already meet your condition, you really do not need to check if there are more than 2. Moreover, if you need to match a regular ASCII space (decimal code 32), you do not need a `REGEXP` operator, you can safely use

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles LIKE '%  %';
```

`LIKE` is preferred in all cases where you can use it instead of `REGEXP` (see [*MySQL | REGEXP VS Like*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646686/mysql-regexp-vs-like))

When you need to match numerous whitespace symbols, you can use `WHERE titles REGEXP '[[:space:]]{2}'` (it will match `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`), and if you only plan to match tabs and spaces, use `WHERE titles REGEXP '[[:blank:]]{2}'`. For more details, see [*POSIX Bracket Expressions*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Note that `[:class_name:]` should only be used inside a character class (i.e. inside another pair of `[...]`, otherwise, they are not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Your POSIX class must be,

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles REGEXP '[[:space:]]{2,}';
```

No need for `,`

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles REGEXP '[[:space:]]{2}';
```

You may also use `[[:blank:]]`

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE titles REGEXP '[[:blank:]]{2}';
```

Comment: sorry, I must find 2 spaces or more. I am going to edit the question. sorry again

Comment: ya, atleast two spaces.. My regex should satisfy the rules.

Comment: This finds exactly two: '[[:space:]]{2}'

Comment: @Musa atleast two or more. So exactly 2 comes within atleast two.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just the space character:  `REGEXP '  '`.  Or you could use `LIKE "%  %"`, which would be faster.  (Note: there are 2 blanks in those.)

Otherwise, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html for `blank` and `space`.