# LIKE CONCAT vs REGEXP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I want to select the row of my mysql database which contains a word from a string, which is a php variable.
I found two ways:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$string' REGEXP word_column"
```

and

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$string' LIKE CONCAT('%',word_column,'%')"
```

For example, if my database is:

```
id | word_column
 0 | red
 1 | blue
 2 | green
 ...
```

Then

```
<?php
...
$string = 'This string contains word red, so I want mysql to return row 0!';
$best_query = ""; //HERE GOES ONE OF THE QUERIES ABOVE
$result_i_want = mysqli_query($db_connect, $best_query);
...
?>
```

Both queries works, but which is the one with best performance?

Comment: In general, `like` is going to be faster than `regexp`...

Comment: and neither will be as fast as using a fulltext index, however... can't see how an index would help match words in a table against a full string.

Comment: My guess is that which is faster will be dependent on the actual data; `like` might be faster than `regexp` generally (as sgeddes stated), but you'd also need to figure in the cost of the `CONCAT` you've used with it (_on long strings that could get relatively expensive_).

Comment: Why on Earth don't you test the performance of the 2 queries yourself?

Comment: [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) would be another possible option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL | REGEXP VS Like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646686/mysql-regexp-vs-like)

Comment: Will you always look for the entire word?  If so the answer is "neither".

Comment: @RickJames I look for the entire word, which is best way then?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$string' LIKE CONCAT('%',word_column,'%')"
```

is faster. As commenters noted, performance depends upon on your dataset to some extent also.

Comment: The only question here is "which is the one with best performance?". Why do you feel I did not answer that?

Answer (score 0):

For searching for the *entire column*, don't use `LIKE` or `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT ... WHERE word_column = '$string'
-- and have
INDEX(word_column)
```

For searching for word(s) *embedded in a string*:

```
SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(string_column) AGAINST ('+$string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
-- and have
FULTEXT(string_column)
```

(Study the documentation about FULLTEXT; there are some restrictions.)