# MySQL Exclude Over Include in FIND_IN_SET()

Tags: mysql, left-join, find-in-set

For example, I have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id     |    title     |                        tags                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     | Title 1      |  funny, adventure                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2     | Title Two    |  funny, short, horror                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3     | Title III    |  funny, short, adventure                       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I query that I want to include **funny** or **short** but exclude **horror** in the results? Like the exclude will overpower even if one of its include criteria matches?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id     |    title     |                        tags                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     | Title 1      |  funny, adventure                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3     | Title III    |  funny, short, adventure                       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE NOT find_in_set('horror',tags) <> 0
```

Comment: It will still return the records with horror tags.

Comment: Remove spaces from comma separated values then run query with find_in_set

Comment: You can also try this SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE tags NOT LIKE "%horror%"

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. Yes that works now. Also working is using the REGEXP. I decided to use the REGEXP because of performance issues of LIKE clauses.

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tags NOT REGEXP 'horror';

Comment: Read out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646686/mysql-regexp-vs-like