# Building Multiple LIKE Operator Prepared Statement at run-time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Table **tbl** columns
**col1**   |  **col**  | **col3**

SQL I want to use with prepared statement with binding the parameter at runtime

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from tbl 
where col1=10 
and col2 between 0 and 10 and col3 like '%QUERY%';
```

The problem is that filtering on col3 depends on the user inputs. If only 2 terms are used then it should be

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from tbl 
where col1=10 
and col2 between 0 and 10 and (col3 like '%QUERY%' AND col3 like '%QUERY2%');
```

If 3 inputs are found then it should be

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from tbl 
where col1=10 
and col2 between 0 and 10 and (col3 like '%QUERY%' AND col3 like '%QUERY2%' AND col3 like '%QUERY3%');
```

I want to use only Prepared Statement and not a direct query. I know the same can be achieved by sanitizing the input and running a direct query still I only prefer Prepared Statements.

**How to achieve this ?**

Below the code I have :( with open SQL injection

```
$terms=explode(",",$_POST['txtD']);
$sql='';                     
for($i=0;$i<count($terms);$i++) {
    $terms[$i] = trim($terms[$i]);
    if ($i!=$count-1)
        $sql = $sql."`Places` LIKE '%$terms[$i]%' AND ";
    else
        $sql = $sql."`Places` LIKE '%$terms[$i]%'";
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"select col1, col2, col3 from tbl where col1=? and col2 between ? and ? and ".$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iii", $param1, $param2, $param3);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: The prepare SQL is just a string. You can build that and save the values in an array for later use for the binds.

Comment: There is no need for parenthesis since you are only using the `AND` clause. This is utterly trivial by using `implode()` but since you're not showing what you have tried it is impossible to assist with your specific problem

Comment: If you're going to be binding the parameter at runtime, it should look like `col3 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider building your `LIKE` expression portion of prepared SQL statement using `implode`. Then build a param arguments to be run with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
$terms = explode(",", str_replace(",", " ,", $_POST['txtD']));

// PREPARED STATEMENT BUILD
$likes = [];
foreach($terms as $t) {
    $likes[] = "col3 LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
}

$expr = implode(" or ", $likes);
$sql = "select col1, col2, col3 from tbl ".
       "where col1=? and col2 between ? and ? and (". $expr .")";

// PARAM ARG BUILD
$type = 'iii' . str_repeat("s", count($terms));
$sql_params = array_merge(array($stmt, $type, $param1, $param2, $param3), $terms);

// PREPARE AND EXECUTE QUERY
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', sql_params);    
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

[SQL and Param Build Demo](https://rextester.com/IOIYG35337)

---

Alternatively, consider MySQL's `REGEXP` for a regex expression using pipes to denote `OR` logic:

```php
// REPACE COMMAS BY PIPE
$terms = str_replace(",", "|", str_replace(",", " ,", $_POST['txtD']));

$sql = "select col1, col2, col3 from tbl " .
       "where col1=? and col2 between ? and ? and col3 regexp ?";

// PREPARE AND EXECUTE QUERY
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con);    
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iii", $param1, $param2, $param3, $terms);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Do note as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16646686/1422451) `REGEXP` is slower in execution than the equivalent `LIKE` expression.