# difference between REGEXP and LIKE?

Tags: mysql

Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates

select distinct city from station where city LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL | REGEXP VS Like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646686/mysql-regexp-vs-like)

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing this.  If you want to use `LIKE`, you'll need to have separate checks for each starting vowel:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city LIKE 'a%' OR city LIKE 'e%' OR city LIKE 'i%' OR
      city LIKE 'u%' OR city LIKE 'u%';
```

If you can use `REGEXP`, it is possible to write the above logic more succinctly:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE city REGEXP '^[aeiou]';  -- ^ means starts with a vowel letter
```