# How to find variable pattern in MySql with Regex?

Tags: mysql, regex, substring, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I am trying to pull a product code from a long set of string formatted like a URL address.  The pattern is always 3 letters followed by 3 or 4 numbers (ex. ???### or ???####).  I have tried using REGEXP and LIKE syntax, but my results are off for both/I am not sure which operators to use.

The first select statement is close to trimming the URL to show just the code, but oftentimes will show a random string of numbers it may find in the URL string.

The second select statement is more rudimentary, but I am unsure which operators to use.

Which would be the quickest solution?

```
SELECT columnName, SUBSTR(columnName, LOCATE(columnName REGEXP "[^=\-][a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{3,4}", columnName), LENGTH(columnName) - LOCATE(columnName REGEXP "[^=\-][a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{3,4}", REVERSE(columnName))) AS extractedData FROM tableName

SELECT columnName FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE '%___###%' OR columnName LIKE '%___####%' 
-- Will take a substring of this result as well
```

Example Data:

randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-xyz123&hello_world=us&etc_etc

In this case, the desired string is "xyz123" and the location of said pattern is variable based on each entry.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT column, LOCATE(column REGEXP "([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}$)", column), SUBSTR(column, LOCATE(column REGEXP "([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}$)", column), LENGTH(column) - LOCATE(column REGEXP "^.*[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}", REVERSE(column))) AS extractData From mainTable
```

This expression is still not grabbing the right data, but I feel like it may get me closer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646686/mysql-regexp-vs-like

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am running My SQL 8.0+

Comment: Then try `REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '(?<=[&?]random_code=[^&#]{0,256}-)[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}(?![^&#])')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd make use of capture groups:
`(?<=[=\-\\])([a-zA-Z]{3}[\d]{3,4})(?=[&])`
I assume with `[^=\-]` you wanted to capture string with "-","\" or "=" in front but not include those chars in the result. To do that use "positive lookbehind" `(?<=`.
I also added a lookahead `(?=` for "&".
If you'd like to fidget more with regex I recommend [RegExr](https://regexr.com)

Comment: Will select starting part if the number of digits is more than 4... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e70332ec01e3cb1723957ea8f142bd0

Comment: @Revuimar I do not need to capture any "-" or "=" characters; I was hoping it would help with testing purposes to see where my match began.

Comment: @Akina in your 4th output example there are five digits, so no match should be detected I would hope

Comment: @Gordon This is true, and this is the problem of the provided solution. I hope that the answer author will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '(?<=[&?]random_code=[^&#]{0,256}-)[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}(?![^&#])')
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=[&?]random_code=[^&#]{0,256}-)` - immediately on the left, there must be `&` or `&`, `random_code=`, and then zero to 256 chars other than `&` and `#` followed with a `-` char
- `[a-zA-Z]{3}` - three ASCII letters
- `[0-9]{3,4}` - three to four ASCII digits
- `(?![^&#])` - that are followed either with `&`, `#` or end of string.

See the [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d69a5071127548a1d5c31b8598d41861):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 'randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-xyz123&hello_world=us&etc_etc' val
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-xyz4567&hello_world=us&etc_etc'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-xyz89&hello_world=us&etc_etc'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-xyz00000&hello_world=us&etc_etc'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'randomwebsite.com/3982356923abcd1ab?random_code=12480712_ABC_DEF_ANOTHER_CODE-aaaaa11111&hello_world=us&etc_etc')
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(val,'(?<=[&?]random_code=[^&#]{0,256}-)[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,4}(?![^&#])') output
FROM cte
```

Output:

[image]